# How to use QTP repository objects site-wide?

Tags: qtp

Is there a way to use objects in the QTP object repository on any page without binding them to certain page?

Here is an example:

I have a website with top level navigation (Home, Archive, Forum, About, Contact). QTP stores these links in the object repository under certain page. For example:

Browser Google

-- Page Homepage

---- Link: Home

---- Link: Archive

---- Link: Forum

---- Link: About

---- Link: Contact

Now I want to access `Link: Home` from a page other than `Homepage`, let's say from the `Archive` page. Do I need to store the link objects under the `Archive` page object or is there a way to access the links from any page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the Description properties in the Object Repository. Right now, you probably see a description for the Homepage object with Name `Title` and Value `Homepage`. You can delete or change this description (you can use regular expressions as Wildcard match) to match more than exactly a page with title 'Homepage'. Sometimes you have to do the same for the Browser object that is the parent for this page.

Please note that:

- When you broaden your recognition scope, chances are that the wrong page is matched or, if there are multiple pages on the screen matching the same description, no page is recognized because they are not unique. Ways to solve this: Use a unique property that is valid for both pages or as a last resort the ordinal identifier
- When you are learning new objects from the page, they are learned under a new page (and not the one you just changed the description of) and you have to merge both pages. That can be a pain in QTP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I haven't thought of that solution. Is this a common way to handle this problem? It seems a bit like a hack to me. Isn't there a cleaner way to do it in QTP?

Comment: Very common. Sometimes the title of a page is dynamic, but there are also times that QTP records certain properties that are variable and not needed for the recognition, you can simply delete them. Sometimes you have text with variable parts in it like a link: [View my 42 mail messages](http://example.com). Then you need to build a regular expression `^View my \d+ mail messages$`. Just play with it, but save and backup regularly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will give this a try. Do I understand you right, that I can try to place all objects that I work with under one (flexible) page (i.e. identified with some loose regex) to avoid object duplication in OR?

Comment: That is right, but you have to see for yourself if you like that way of working. You'll fail in page recognition when there are multiple pages open at the same time that matches the same loose regex. Making the GUI Map a bit more generic is good, it will save you time and work, but keep it in balance.